# Generic code to convert a list of objects into a tree structure

Tags: rust

I have some menus with a tree structure, defined like this:

```
use rocket::serde::Deserialize;
use rocket::serde::Serialize;
use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_models::MenuResource;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct MenuResponse {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub name_zh: String,
    pub parent_id: i32,
    pub disableCheckbox: bool,
    pub tree_id_path: String,
    pub children: Vec<MenuResponse>
}
```

In the database I store the menus as a list with `id` and `parent_id`. I transform the list to a tree like this:

```
/**
** convert the list menu to tree recursive
**/
pub fn convert_menu_to_tree(root_menus: &Vec<MenuResource>, sub_menus: &Vec<MenuResource>) -> Vec<MenuResponse>{
    let mut menu_res_list = Vec::new();
    for root_menu in root_menus {
        let mut origin_menu_res_list = Vec::new();
        let mut menu_res = MenuResponse::from(root_menu);
        for sub_menu in sub_menus{
            if sub_menu.parent_id == root_menu.id {
                let menu_res_sub = MenuResponse::from(sub_menu);
                menu_res.children.push(menu_res_sub);
                origin_menu_res_list.push(sub_menu.clone());
            }
        }
        if !menu_res.children.is_empty() {
            menu_res.children = convert_menu_to_tree(&origin_menu_res_list, sub_menus);
        }
        menu_res_list.push(menu_res);
    }
    return menu_res_list;
}
```

This code works fine. The problem is that I have another datatype I want to treat as tree structure like this. I have to write the list to tree conversion function for each one. Is it possible to write a function to handle all data structure like this? One function to convert all list objects to tree structure.

In Java, I could using generics and reflection to do it. How about in Rust?

I have tried to define the function the generic way like this:

```
/**
** convert the list menu to tree recursive
**/
pub fn convert_menu_to_tree<T,E>(root_menus: &Vec<T>, sub_menus: &Vec<T>) -> Vec<E>{
    let mut menu_res_list = Vec::new();
    for root_menu in root_menus {
        let mut origin_menu_res_list = Vec::new();
        let mut menu_res = E::from(root_menu);
        for sub_menu in sub_menus{
            if sub_menu.parent_id == root_menu.id {
                let menu_res_sub = E::from(sub_menu);
                menu_res.children.push(menu_res_sub);
                origin_menu_res_list.push(sub_menu.clone());
            }
        }
        if !menu_res.children.is_empty() {
            menu_res.children = convert_menu_to_tree(&origin_menu_res_list, sub_menus);
        }
        menu_res_list.push(menu_res);
    }
    return menu_res_list;
}
```

But I don't know how to handle the `children` attribute with `T` or `E`. Is is possible to set the value by name `children`?

Comment: Yes, of course you can do that. What did you try?

Comment: I have tried to define the entity as generic way, but still not figure out how to set the generic value. @PeterHall

Comment: Try adding <T>: `fn convert_menu_to_tree<T>`. You might also need a bounds like: `fn convert_menu_to_tree<T: Into<MenuResponse>>`.

Comment: @Dogbert I think it's a little more complex, as T also needs to be capable of querying its own and its parent id

Comment: @Finomnis yep you're right, this would require a custom trait that allows access to `id` and `parent_id`. Or, if the function's signature can be changed, a callback to `T -> (id, parent_id)` (like in `slice::sort_by_key`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your example wasn't quite a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I re-wrote it (sorry, stretches the definition of 'minimal' a little) to play around with:

```rust
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MenuResource {
    parent_id: i32,
    id: i32,
    content: i32,
}

impl MenuResource {
    pub fn new(parent_id: i32, id: i32, content: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            parent_id,
            id,
            content,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct MenuResponse {
    pub id: i32,
    pub content: i32,
    pub children: Vec<MenuResponse>,
}

impl From<&MenuResource> for MenuResponse {
    fn from(src: &MenuResource) -> Self {
        Self {
            id: src.id,
            content: src.content,
            children: vec![],
        }
    }
}

/**
** convert the list menu to tree recursive
**/
pub fn convert_menu_to_tree(
    root_menus: &Vec<MenuResource>,
    sub_menus: &Vec<MenuResource>,
) -> Vec<MenuResponse> {
    let mut menu_res_list = Vec::new();
    for root_menu in root_menus {
        let mut origin_menu_res_list: Vec<MenuResource> = Vec::new();
        let mut menu_res = MenuResponse::from(root_menu);
        for sub_menu in sub_menus {
            if sub_menu.parent_id == root_menu.id {
                let menu_res_sub = MenuResponse::from(sub_menu);
                menu_res.children.push(menu_res_sub);
                origin_menu_res_list.push((*sub_menu).clone());
            }
        }
        if !menu_res.children.is_empty() {
            menu_res.children = convert_menu_to_tree(&origin_menu_res_list, sub_menus);
        }
        menu_res_list.push(menu_res);
    }
    return menu_res_list;
}

pub fn main() {
    let root_menus = vec![MenuResource::new(0, 1, 101), MenuResource::new(0, 2, 102)];
    let sub_menus = vec![
        MenuResource::new(1, 3, 201),
        MenuResource::new(1, 4, 202),
        MenuResource::new(2, 5, 203),
        MenuResource::new(3, 6, 204),
        MenuResource::new(6, 7, 205),
    ];

    let result = convert_menu_to_tree(&root_menus, &sub_menus);
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&result).unwrap());
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "content": 101,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "content": 201,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "content": 204,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 7,
                "content": 205,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "content": 202,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "content": 102,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "content": 203,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The `Serialize` and `json` is of course not strictly necessary, but the output is very unreadable otherwise, and I was too lazy to write a proper `Display` impl.

---

### Interface

Now, let's see what we need to make the `convert_menu_to_tree` function more generic (let's rename it `convert_to_tree`):

- A type, `T` that we want to convert to a tree
- An output type
- A function that takes `&T` and a list of children and creates the output type
- A function that reads the `id` and the `parent_id` from `T`.

Therefore, let's define a trait `IntoTree` for that type `T`:

```rust
pub trait IntoTree: Sized {
    type Output;

    fn get_id(&self) -> i32;
    fn get_parent_id(&self) -> i32;
    fn convert(&self, children: Vec<Self::Output>) -> Self::Output;
}
```

---

### Solution

Now here is an algorithm that puts it all together:

*convert_to_tree.rs*

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait IntoTree: Sized {
    type Output;

    fn get_id(&self) -> i32;
    fn get_parent_id(&self) -> i32;
    fn convert(&self, children: Vec<Self::Output>) -> Self::Output;
}

fn take_all_children<T>(parent_id: i32, sub_menus: &mut HashMap<i32, Vec<&T>>) -> Vec<T::Output>
where
    T: IntoTree,
{
    sub_menus
        .remove(&parent_id)
        .unwrap_or_default()
        .iter()
        .map(|child| {
            let grandchildren = take_all_children(child.get_id(), sub_menus);
            child.convert(grandchildren)
        })
        .collect()
}

pub fn convert_to_tree<T>(root_menus: &[T], sub_menus: &[T]) -> Vec<T::Output>
where
    T: IntoTree,
{
    let mut sub_menus_by_parent = HashMap::new();
    for sub in sub_menus {
        sub_menus_by_parent
            .entry(sub.get_parent_id())
            .or_insert_with(Vec::new)
            .push(sub);
    }

    root_menus
        .iter()
        .map(|root_menu| {
            let children = take_all_children(root_menu.get_id(), &mut sub_menus_by_parent);
            root_menu.convert(children)
        })
        .collect()
}
```

*main.rs*

```rust
mod convert_to_tree;
use convert_to_tree::{convert_to_tree, IntoTree};

use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MenuResource {
    parent_id: i32,
    id: i32,
    content: i32,
}

impl MenuResource {
    pub fn new(parent_id: i32, id: i32, content: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            parent_id,
            id,
            content,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct MenuResponse {
    pub id: i32,
    pub content: i32,
    pub children: Vec<MenuResponse>,
}

impl IntoTree for MenuResource {
    type Output = MenuResponse;

    fn get_id(&self) -> i32 {
        self.id
    }

    fn get_parent_id(&self) -> i32 {
        self.parent_id
    }

    fn convert(&self, children: Vec<Self::Output>) -> Self::Output {
        MenuResponse {
            id: self.id,
            content: self.content,
            children,
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let root_menus = vec![MenuResource::new(0, 1, 101), MenuResource::new(0, 2, 102)];
    let sub_menus = vec![
        MenuResource::new(1, 3, 201),
        MenuResource::new(1, 4, 202),
        MenuResource::new(2, 5, 203),
        MenuResource::new(3, 6, 204),
        MenuResource::new(6, 7, 205),
    ];

    let result = convert_to_tree(&root_menus, &sub_menus);
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&result).unwrap());
}
```

With this, you can now convert every type that implements `IntoTree` to a tree.

The conversion should be very fast as it first builds a `HashMap` of ids and children. Then, it just takes the children for every node out of the `HashMap`.

---

### Alternative Solution

Just for reference, another solution that is closer to your code:

*convert_to_tree.rs*

```rust
pub trait IntoTree: Sized + Clone {
    type Output;

    fn get_id(&self) -> i32;
    fn get_parent_id(&self) -> i32;
    fn convert(&self, children: Vec<Self::Output>) -> Self::Output;
}

pub fn convert_to_tree<T>(root_menus: &[T], sub_menus: &[T]) -> Vec<T::Output>
where
    T: IntoTree,
{
    let mut menu_res_list = Vec::new();
    for root_menu in root_menus {
        let mut origin_menu_res_list: Vec<T> = Vec::new();

        for sub_menu in sub_menus {
            if sub_menu.get_parent_id() == root_menu.get_id() {
                origin_menu_res_list.push(sub_menu.clone());
            }
        }

        let children = convert_to_tree(&origin_menu_res_list, sub_menus);

        let menu_res = root_menu.convert(children);
        menu_res_list.push(menu_res);
    }
    return menu_res_list;
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is the use of `.clone` and the `Clone` requirement for `T`.